# Spring Data JPA Repositories

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository definition like

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

In the Spring context file I have

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.package"/>
```

Then I try to do something like

```
new Repositories(applicationContext).getRepositoryFor(User.class);
```

but I get the error

> Method "getRepositoryFor" with signature
>   "(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository;"
>   is not applicable on this object

Does anyone have any idea what could have I done wrong?

Comment: `domainClass`evaluates to `User.class`?

Comment: Yes. I copy/pasted my code. Now I edited the question to clearly reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels more like a version incompatibility between the Spring Data JPA module and Spring Data Commons. Make sure you use the version of Spring Data Commons that is referred to from the `pom.xml` of the Spring Data JPA version you use. Or, even better: do not declare a dependency on Spring Data Commons at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue. As Oliver notes, it is a version incompatibility between Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Commons.

One version of `Repositories.getRepositoryFor()` returns a `CrudRepository` and the other returns an `Object`, <s>presumably to accommodate `PagingAndSortingRepository`</s> to accommodate `Repository`. [Edited per Oliver's comment below.]

Comment: Sort of :). To enable Spring Data REST to work with repositories that implement `Repository` only, we had to drop the return type of `CrudRepository` and fall back of plain `Object`.

Comment: Oh, yup, makes sense.