# Spring Data JPA - insert a base class into the repository

Tags: java, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have a small application being a bridge between RabbitMQ and SQL database. It is meant to consume events (of few types) from the queue and store them in appropriate tables in the DB. In majority of cases, there is almost no processing between the Event and the Entity (just field copying). This is the reason why I have injected a Dozer mapper that makes the conversion - it works flawlessly. The difficult part is saving a generic object to the repository without having to use `switch` + `instanceof` as a last resort.

Code:

```
@Service
public class EventProcessorImpl implements EventProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private Mapper mapper; // a Dozer mapper instance

    @Override
    public void process(final BaseEvent event) {
        final BaseEntity entity = mapper.map(event, BaseEntity.class);

        // TODO save the entity to the database after it's transformed
    }
}
```

The `BaseEntity` is a base class for entites, as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private String guid;

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(final String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }
}
```

---

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity>
                 extends CrudRepository<T, String> {
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface EmailOpenedRepository
                 extends BaseRepository<EmailOpened> {
}
```

The question is - how to save the entity, given that:

1. it is passed as a base class (what I consider as an advantage, but this can be changed)
2. there are quite a couple of event types (now 5, but can explode to 30 in a few months)

What I have tried:

1. I have `@Autowired` an instance of `BaseRepository` and tried calling `repository.save(entity)`, but it fails on app startup due to multiple bean definitions available.
2. Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880185/spring-data-jpa-repositories), I have successfully implemented the following, but I don't know whether this is a correct approach:

   ```
   public void process(final BaseEvent event) {
       final BaseEntity entity = mapper.map(event, BaseEntity.class);
       final CrudRepository repository = (CrudRepository) new Repositories(context)
                   .getRepositoryFor(entity.getClass());

       repository.save(entity);
   }
   ```
3. I thought of iterating over all available beans of `BaseRepository` and finding the one that will support this type (`findFirst(repository -> repository.supports(entity.getType()))`, but Spring Data JPA repositories are interfaces and I cannot store the supported type in the interface.

Comment: You should be able to get the generic type parameter when it's in the public signature.

Comment: @chrylis Could you elaborate on your hint?